# Robot not merge with odometry

Tags: navigation, ros, amr, odometry

i am newly working on ros. I got odometry value from two motor, but i  cannot merge with odometry value with my robot in rviz.   that odometry value keep on moving but my robot idle at one point  In rviz. kindly helps to overcome this issue. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: Warm welcome to SO. Please try to use correct upper case letters, e.g. in the beginning of your title, sentences or the word "I". This would be gentle to your readers. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Then update your question with code to show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 1):

The fixed frame in rviz that you’re viewing is wrong. We cannot see from the screenshot, but it acts like a static frame, such as base_link.

To fix this expand the right side and under fixed_frame choose something that’s not static; e.g. `odom`